# Moving items left and right from two listboxes

Tags: powershell, user-interface, listbox

I have a Gui with 2 listboxes like so:
[image]

This should be an installer where the user pick programs from left move them to the right and select install, and all the programs to the right will be installed.
I have a problem with the button functions moving from left to right and from right to left. When I do this:

```
Function MoveRight (){
       $x = $listbox1.selecteditems
       @($x) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox2.Items.Add($_)}}
```

I get the items to the right but when the user presses that button again I see duplication there.
I'm struggeling with how can I make it test if the selected items on the left already exists on the right and if so just ignore that.

I cannot do a check if listbox1.selecteditem eq to listbox2.selecteditem because the user will isn't supposeded to check items from listbox2 (unless he wants to remove them).

Any idea how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .Items.Clear() Method on the right listbox before adding elements there:

```
Function MoveRight (){
       $listbox2.Items.Clear()
       $x = $listbox1.selecteditems
       @($x) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox2.Items.Add($_)}}
```

Comment: This is nice approach but this doesnt help if the user just forgot to add one program to the left, in case he has 10 programs to the right and now he just checks another program on the left it will remove all items from the right

Comment: this will move items to right, removing it from left at the same time:
```Function MoveRight (){
$x = $listbox1.selecteditems
@($x) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox2.Items.Add($_); [void]     $Listbox1.Items.Remove($_)}
}```